# How to use custom sound for react-native-onesignal push notifications on android?

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, onesignal

I'm having trouble using a custom sound for react-native-onesignal push notifications. I have used the exact same sound file for an old ionic app without problems but I can't get it working in react-native.

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/customize-notification-sounds

Paths I've added the file to:

project/android/app/src/main/res/raw/bells.mp3

project/android/res/raw/bells.mp3

project/res/raw/bells.mp3

I have also tried adding a file named onesignal_default_sound.mp3 to replace default sound like the docs say but it has no effect.

```
let otherParams = {
  "android_sound": "bells", // I have tried bells.mp3 also
  "priority": 10,
  ...customOtherParams
}    
OneSignal.postNotification(content, data, playerId, otherParams)
```

Notifications still play default android sound

Comment: I am also facing this issue. Are you able to get the root cause of this issue?

Comment: @ZeeshanAfzalSatti Are you found a solution?

Comment: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-notification-categories
@OliverD Basically I implement using the above `One Signal Categories`. Set the category of notification dynamically on the backend side. It's worked for both android + ios.